# Using Alias In When Portion of a Case Statement in Oracle SQL

Tags: sql, oracle, case, alias

I've been trying to look up for awhile now if it's possible to use an alias stated earlier in the select statement if it can be used in a case later in the case statement for Oracle SQL. Most results I find are about how to make an Alias based on a case statement which isn't the same problem. A quick example would be something like:

```
Select TABLEA.SomeIDNumber AS "Id",
       case ID
          when 3
          then 'foo'
          else 'bar'
       end AS "Results"
FROM OMEGA.TABLEA
```

It's really not that simple in the SQL Statement I'm creating (it's actually created based on a previous case statement and requires some joins on various tables to do the full other pats of the query, but it wouldn't really make sense without knowing more of the database which I can't share).

I'm just wondering if it's possible to use an alias in a case statement later in the select statement for Oracle (I know such things can be done with Access kinda "SQL"). Or is it better for me to do some reworking of the select to make it nested select statements? Probably doable, just a bit more of a pain.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

No, you can't refer to the alias elsewhere in the same level of `select`, other than in the `order by` clause, because of when Oracle assigns it internally.

[From the documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e26088/queries002.htm#sthref2213) (emphasis added):

> You can use a column alias, c_alias, to label the immediately
>   preceding expression in the select list so that the column is
>   displayed with a new heading. The alias effectively renames the select
>   list item for the duration of the query. **The alias can be used in the
>   `ORDER BY` clause, but not other clauses in the query**.

You would need to use an inner query, something like:

```
select "Id",
    case "Id"
        when 3
        then 'foo'
        else 'bar'
    end AS "Results"
from (
    select TABLEA.SomeIDNumber AS "Id",
    from TABLEA
);
```

Comment: Ah, oh well, guess I'll have to do that. That'll make this SQL query fun lol. Thanks.

Comment: Should give a follow up, if the case is calling another table used as a join inside the nested select, do you have to do another join on the top select or can you call the information from the table in the inner select?

never quite done a select like this (poorly maintained database has made this ridiculous for me :/ )

Comment: @TheGodEmperor - er, not quite sure I follow. You directly reference a table in the inner select from the outer one, as you're just working with a result set; you'd need a new join in the outer level. But normally I'd try to expose any values from a joined table that I need in the outer select, by including them in the select list for the inner query; they don't have to appear in the select list of the outer query but can still be referred to. There may be issues that prevent that, it would depend on the actual query.