# Referencing identifier in Case statement from another Case statement

Tags: sql, oracle, case, alias

So I have one case statement that looks like this: (redacted actual reportcodes)

```
select
     case
        when t1.reportcode in ('x', 'y', 'z') then 'AFMC'
        when t2.reportcode in ('x', 'y', 'z') then 'AFMC'
        when t1.reportcode in ('x', 'y', 'z') then 'FOH'
        when t2.reportcode in ('x', 'y', 'z') then 'FOH'
        when t1.reportcode in ('x', 'y', 'z') then 'Forest Service'
        when t2.reportcode in ('x', 'y', 'z') then 'Forest Service'
        when t1.reportcode in ('x', 'y', 'z') then 'HHS-Strive'
        when t2.reportcode in ('x', 'y', 'z') then 'HHS-Strive'
        when t1.reportcode in ('x', 'y', 'z') then 'NASA'
        when t2.reportcode in ('x', 'y', 'z') then 'NASA'
        when t1.reportcode in ('x', 'y', 'z') then 'VA SLC'
        when t2.reportcode in ('x', 'y', 'z') then 'VA SLC'
        when t1.reportcode in ('x', 'y', 'z') then 'ABMC'
        when t2.reportcode in ('x', 'y', 'z') then 'ABMC'
        when t1.reportcode in ('x', 'y', 'z') then 'DFAS'
        when t2.reportcode in ('x', 'y', 'z') then 'DFAS'
        when t1.reportcode in ('x', 'y', 'z') then 'DON'
        when t2.reportcode in ('x', 'y', 'z') then 'DON'
     end as FirstGroups,
```

That checks all these codes and gives it an identifier (ABMC, AFMC, etc...) if the codes match up.

Following this, I have another case statement that looks like this:

```
case
        when 'ABMC' not in FirstGroups then 'ABMC N/A'
        when 'AFMC' not in FirstGroups then 'AFMC N/A'
        when 'DFAS' not in FirstGroups then 'DFAS N/A'
        when 'DON' not in FirstGroups then 'DON N/A'
        when 'FOH' not in FirstGroups then 'FOH N/A'
        when 'Forest Service' not in FirstGroups then 'Forest Service N/A'
        when 'HHS-Strive' not in FirstGroups then 'HHS-Strive N/A'
        when 'NASA' not in FirstGroups then 'NASA N/A'
        when 'VA SLC' not in FirstGroups then 'VA SLC N/A'
 end as NotApplicable,
```

The goal here is to look through the output I got from the first case statement and if one of the identifiers like 'VA SLC' or 'ABMC' *is not* in there, then it would put it out in its own column saying 'VA SLC N/A', 'ABMC N/A' etc... Unfortunately I cannot reference that FirstGroups identifier from the first case statement in my second case statement. I tried using t1.reportcode and t2.reportcode as well but those didn't work.

Expected output would look like this:

```
FirstGroups            NotApplicable
ABMC                   AFMC N/A
DFAS                   NASA N/A
DON
FOH
Forest Service
NASA
VA SLC
```

Or something similar to that.

Let me know if you have any ideas on how I can do this. Thanks!

Comment: What is 'not in' supposed to be doing here? FirstGroups is a scalar value, so it's the same as not equals here, and that means you can only get 'ABMC N/A' or 'AFMC N/A' - the rest of the cases can never be reached?

Comment: Referencing the alias for the first case in the second is a duplicate [of this question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/17591707/266304); but that seems to only be part of the problem.

Comment: Well the intention was to check whether 'ABMC' or any of the others are included in the FirstGroups case output column. If any are not in that column, it should output in another column 'ABMC N/A' and the like. Sounds like using 'not in' is not correct here though.

Comment: Not in the column for any row? You could do that analytically, but you would still only show one N/A value for the entire set (or partition). Maybe showing a simplified version with actual (fake) data and expected results would help. Although... the question you actually asked has been answered?

Comment: [Here's a slightly simplified demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/b87bc/2) showing what I mean; all of the first case's conditions (in the inline view) are met, but only the first two conditions of the second case (in the outer query) are ever met.

Comment: Ok, initial question was edited with expected output.

Comment: @Alex Poole - I do see what you mean, thanks for the example. I don't know how to effectively fix that though.

Comment: There's no relationship between the values in the two columns in your final output though, right?

Comment: Not other than I want the second column to be able to see the first one and determine whether certain report names (ABMC, FOH, etc) are missing and return that.

Comment: Do you have a table that links the report codes to the group names? Or do they have to be hard-coded?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `not in FirstGroups` suggests you're trying to treat the all the values in that column as a collection, and exclude the members of that collection from the list of all groups to form the second column; which is unrelated to the value in the first column for the same row. Your example output seems to support that.

This seems like something the client should be dealing with - you query to get the first groups, and know (or separately query) the list of all groups, and have the client display appropriately.

You can do it in SQL, it's just a bit messy, particularly without being able to use CTEs.

This uses two inline views; the first gets the `firstgroups` values you already have, though I've added a distinct based on your expected output; the second gets the not applicable values by using your fixed list of group names and excluding those that are in `firstgroups`. Unfortunately because you can't use a CTE that means repeating your original case statement to do the exclusion.

Each of those inline views adds an analytic rank column, so the `firstgroups` in your example gets rows ranked 1-7, and the second gets rows ranked 1-2.

Those two inline views are then outer joined with that rank as the join condition.

```
select fg.groupname as firstgroups, na.notapplicable
from (
  select groupname, dense_rank() over (order by groupname) as rnk
  from (
    select distinct case
        when t1.reportcode in (1, 2, 3) then 'AFMC'
        when t1.reportcode in (4, 5, 6) then 'FOH'
        when t1.reportcode in (7, 8, 9) then 'Forest Service'
        when t1.reportcode in (10, 11, 12) then 'HHS-Strive'
        when t1.reportcode in (13, 14, 15) then 'NASA'
        when t1.reportcode in (16, 17, 18) then 'VA SLC'
        when t1.reportcode in (19, 20, 21) then 'ABMC'
        when t1.reportcode in (22, 23, 24) then 'DFAS'
        when t1.reportcode in (25, 26, 27) then 'DON'
      end as groupname
    from t1
  )
) fg
full outer join (
  select column_value || ' N/A' as notapplicable,
    dense_rank() over (order by column_value) as rnk
  from table(sys.odcivarchar2list('ABMC', 'AFMC', 'DFAS', 'DON', 'FOH',
    'Forest Service', 'HHS-Strive', 'NASA', 'VA SLC')
  ) allgroups
  where not exists (
    select 1
    from (
      select case
        when t1.reportcode in (1, 2, 3) then 'AFMC'
        when t1.reportcode in (4, 5, 6) then 'FOH'
        when t1.reportcode in (7, 8, 9) then 'Forest Service'
        when t1.reportcode in (10, 11, 12) then 'HHS-Strive'
        when t1.reportcode in (13, 14, 15) then 'NASA'
        when t1.reportcode in (16, 17, 18) then 'VA SLC'
        when t1.reportcode in (19, 20, 21) then 'ABMC'
        when t1.reportcode in (22, 23, 24) then 'DFAS'
        when t1.reportcode in (25, 26, 27) then 'DON'
      end as groupname
      from t1
    ) firstgroups
    where firstgroups.groupname = allgroups.column_value
  )
) na
on na.rnk = fg.rnk
order by coalesce(fg.rnk, na.rnk);
```

Which gets:

```
FIRSTGROUPS          NOTAPPLICABLE      
-------------------- --------------------
ABMC                 AFMC N/A            
DFAS                 NASA N/A            
DON                                      
FOH                                      
Forest Service                           
HHS-Strive                               
VA SLC
```

[SQL Fiddle demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/4167b8/1). I've made up report code values to make the matches you showed.

It's a bit shorter with a CTE:

```
with firstgroups as (
  select groupname, dense_rank() over (order by groupname) as rnk
  from (
    select distinct case
        when t1.reportcode in (1, 2, 3) then 'AFMC'
        when t1.reportcode in (4, 5, 6) then 'FOH'
        when t1.reportcode in (7, 8, 9) then 'Forest Service'
        when t1.reportcode in (10, 11, 12) then 'HHS-Strive'
        when t1.reportcode in (13, 14, 15) then 'NASA'
        when t1.reportcode in (16, 17, 18) then 'VA SLC'
        when t1.reportcode in (19, 20, 21) then 'ABMC'
        when t1.reportcode in (22, 23, 24) then 'DFAS'
        when t1.reportcode in (25, 26, 27) then 'DON'
      end as groupname
    from t1
  )
)
select fg.groupname as firstgroups, na.notapplicable
from firstgroups fg
full outer join (
  select column_value || ' N/A' as notapplicable,
    dense_rank() over (order by column_value) as rnk
  from table(sys.odcivarchar2list('ABMC', 'AFMC', 'DFAS', 'DON', 'FOH',
    'Forest Service', 'HHS-Strive', 'NASA', 'VA SLC')
  ) allgroups
  where not exists (
    select 1
    from firstgroups
    where firstgroups.groupname = allgroups.column_value
  )
) na
on na.rnk = fg.rnk
order by coalesce(fg.rnk, na.rnk);
```

[SQL Fiddle demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/4167b8/2) for info, since you don't seem to be abel to use this syntax with your version of SSIS.