# Use column alias in same select

Tags: sql, oracle

How can I use a column alias somewhere else in the same query? Is it possible in Oracle?

Example using EMP_ID:

```
SELECT
    t1.DATE, t2.NAME, t1.ID,
    TO_NUMBER( SUBSTR( t1.NUMBER_ID, - 6)
      || TRIM( TO_CHAR( SUBSTR(EMP_ID, 3, 2), '00' ) ), '999999999999') AS CONTRACT,
    t2.ADDRESS,
    CASE WHEN SUBSTR(t2.COD_EMP, 0, 2) != 'PG' THEN 'PG00'
      || t2.COD_EMP ELSE t2.COD_EMP END AS EMP_ID
FROM
    TABLE_01 t1
    INNER JOIN TABLE_02 t2 .....
```

Comment: No you can't, unless you have a sub-query with the aliased column

Comment: You can use it in the `order by` clause for sure.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Using Alias In When Portion of a Case Statement in Oracle SQL](http://stackoverflow.com/q/17591707/266304) (and many others)

Answer (score 9):

Per standard SQL: All columns in any particular `SELECT` clause are computed "as if" they're all being computed in parallel (to allow some implementation to do precisely that).

As such, you're not allowed to depend on another column defined within the same `SELECT` clause since it's value has not yet been computed.

Answer (score 4):

If you check the [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28286/statements_10002.htm), you will see that you are only allowed to use it in the `order by` clause:

> Specify an alias for the column expression. Oracle Database will use
>   this alias in the column heading of the result set. The AS keyword is
>   optional. The alias effectively renames the select list item for the
>   duration of the query. **The alias can be used in the order_by_clause
>   but not other clauses in the query**.