# Can a calculated Column result be used in a second Column as an input? Oracle SQL

Tags: sql, oracle, case, calculated-columns

I have a SQL query in Oracle that has a calculated Column using case statements. I would like to use the newly created Column as an input to a second calculated column. Please see my code below.

When I try running this, i get the error "PAYER_TYPE": invalid identifier. So would there be a way to use "PAYER_TYPE" values in the second column?

```
SELECT 
CASE 
WHEN TYP IN ('Swap', 'Ton') 
THEN 
    CASE
     WHEN INDX_PAY = 'FIXED' 
     THEN 'FIXED'
     ELSE 'FLAT' 
    END
END AS PAYER_TYPE,

CASE
WHEN TYPE = 'Swaption' 
THEN
    CASE
        WHEN PAYER_TYPE = 'FIXED' 
        THEN PAY_LEG 
        ELSE REC_LEG 
    END
ELSE 0
END AS STRIKE
FROM Hedge.Details
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Use column alias in same select](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34636877/use-column-alias-in-same-select)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are receiving the error because PAYER_TYPE is not a column in Hedge.Details.  Try the following if you really want to use PAYER_TYPE:

```
SELECT
  C1.PAYER_TYPE,
  CASE  
    WHEN C1.TYPE = 'Swaption'  
      THEN
        CASE
          WHEN C1.PAYER_TYPE = 'FIXED' 
          THEN C1.PAY_LEG 
          ELSE C1.REC_LEG 
        END
      ELSE 0
  END AS STRIKE
FROM
(
  SELECT
    CASE
      WHEN TYP IN ('Swap', 'Ton')
        THEN
          CASE
            WHEN INDX_PAY = 'FIXED'
              THEN 'FIXED'
              ELSE 'FLAT'
            END
    END AS PAYER_TYPE,
    TYPE,
    PAY_LEG,
    REC_LEG
  FROM Hedge.Details
) AS C1
```

Your better choice may be to keep it simple and not use the subquery approach as in the following:

```
SELECT
  CASE 
    WHEN TYP IN ('Swap', 'Ton') 
      THEN 
        CASE
          WHEN INDX_PAY = 'FIXED' 
            THEN 'FIXED'
            ELSE 'FLAT' 
          END
  END AS PAYER_TYPE,
  CASE
    WHEN TYPE = 'Swaption' 
      THEN
        CASE
          WHEN TYP IN ('Swap', 'Ton') AND INDX_PAY = 'FIXED' 
            THEN PAY_LEG 
            ELSE REC_LEG 
          END
      ELSE 0
  END AS STRIKE
FROM Hedge.Details
```

Comment: Thank you! That worked great. I think its easier calling the Case statement than creating a sub query. Cheers.

Answer (score 0):

A simple option is an inline view, or - recently - a CTE (common table expression) aka the WITH factoring clause. Something like this:

```
with your_data as
  (select case when ... then ...
               when ... then ...
          end paper_type                       --> PAPER_TYPE gets its value here ...
   from some_table
   where ...
  )
select case when y.paper_type = 'A' then ...   --> ... and is reused here
            when y.paper_type = 'B' then ...
       end result
from your_data y
```

Answer (score 0):

You can generate that column PAYER_TYPE in the subquery, and then use in the outer part

```
  SELECT 
        PAYER_TYPE,
        CASE
        WHEN TYP = 'Swaption' 
        THEN
            CASE
                WHEN PAYER_TYPE = 'FIXED' 
                THEN 'PAY_LEG' 
                ELSE 'REC_LEG'
            END
        ELSE '0'
        END AS STRIKE
    FROM
    (
    WITH Details(TYP,INDX_PAY) AS
    (
     SELECT 'Swap', 'FIXED' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
     SELECT 'Ton' , 'FIX'   FROM DUAL   
    )
    SELECT 
    CASE 
    WHEN TYP IN ('Swap', 'Ton') 
    THEN 
        CASE
         WHEN INDX_PAY = 'FIXED' 
         THEN 'FIXED'
         ELSE 'FLAT' 
        END
    END PAYER_TYPE,
        TYP
    FROM Details
    )

PAYER_TYPE  STRIKE
----------  ------
FIXED       0
FLAT        0
```