# How to use variables in sql calculations

Tags: sql, db2

I have small table

```
[db2inst1@dashmpp-head-0 - Db2wh ~]$ db2 "select * from TEX"

C1                   C2        
-------------------- ----------
                1000 2000      

  1 record(s) selected.
```

And I am trying to use case statement with a small calculation as follows:

```
SELECT c1,
CASE
    WHEN c1 > 0 THEN 10
    WHEN c1 = 30 THEN 5
    ELSE 1
END AS QuantityText,
c2,
100 / QuantityText as UTILIZATION
FROM TEX;
```

Syntax of this is query is correct but when I run this I get:

```
SQL0206N  "QUANTITYTEXT" is not valid in the context where it is used.  
SQLSTATE=42703
```

Without calculations the following query runs fine:

```
[db2inst1@dashmpp-head-0 - Db2wh ~]$ db2 "SELECT c1,
> CASE
>     WHEN c1 > 0 THEN 'The quantity is greater than 30'
>     WHEN c1 = 30 THEN 'The quantity is 30'
>     ELSE 'The quantity is under 30'
> END AS QuantityText,
> c2
> FROM TEX;"

C1                   QUANTITYTEXT                    C2        
-------------------- ------------------------------- ----------
                1000 The quantity is greater than 30 2000      

  1 record(s) selected.
```

I am new to sql and I am not sure what am I doing wrong here. How to use `QuantityText` in calculation? If I hardcode the text in the query it works fine.

What I tried:

1. added `100 / @QuantityText as UTILIZATION`
2. added `100 / bigint(double(QuantityText)) as CPU_UTILIZATION`
3. 

```
    SELECT c1,
    c2,
    100 / QuantityText as UTILIZATION FROM (
    CASE
      WHEN c1 > 0 THEN 10
      WHEN c1 = 30 THEN 5
      ELSE 1
    END AS QuantityText,
    TEX);

SQL0104N  An unexpected token "CASE       WHEN" was found following 
"UTILIZATION FROM ( ".  Expected tokens may include:  "<select>".  
SQLSTATE=42601
```

Comment: You could use a `derived table` or `Common Table Expression <with clause>`.  There are many similar questions asked.  See this one: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17591707/using-alias-in-when-portion-of-a-case-statement-in-oracle-sql  ... Basically, a derived column is not accessible in the same select list.  It is usable in subsequent query expressions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a table expression to "name" the expression you are producing, so you can use it further in external queries.

For example:

```
select
  *,
  100 / QuantityText as UTILIZATION -- used here
from (
  SELECT c1,
  CASE
    WHEN c1 > 0 THEN 10
    WHEN c1 = 30 THEN 5
    ELSE 1
  END AS QuantityText, -- named here
  c2
  FROM TEX
) x
```