# ORACLE Database Error- SQL Error [904] [42000]: ORA-00904: "ENTERS_ETA": invalid identifier

Tags: sql, oracle

I'm trying to run the below SQL query in DBeaver but getting an error:

> SQL Error [907] [42000]: ORA-00907: Missing Right Parenthesis
> Error position line: 24 pos: 909

This error is in -

```
(EXTRACT (SECOND FROM a.service_date) AS servicedate_secs + a.eta) AS enterTS_eta, a.schdev,
```

Part of the query:

```
SELECT
    (EXTRACT (SECOND FROM a.service_date)  + a.eta) AS enterTS_eta, 
    a.schdev,    -- ADD - enter timestamp AND ETA
    (CASE 
         WHEN enterTS_eta < a.schdev 
             THEN 'Schedule Deviation is more!'   -- Cases TO compare it WITH SchDev
         WHEN enterTS_eta > a.schdev 
             THEN 'Schedule Deviation is less!'
         ELSE 'Equal!'
     END) AS bus_log_info
```

I tried different solutions like

- Removing parenthesis
- Removing AS clauses

Nothing has worked so far. I don't know what's wrong with this part. After trying a few fixes now the error is-

```
SQL Error [904] [42000]: ORA-00904: "ENTERS_ETA": invalid identifier.
```

Comment: You are trying to alias one element in a calculated column - which makes no sense. Remove “ AS servicedate_secs”

Comment: I tried that as well. But it gives me - SQL Error [904] [42000]: ORA-00904: "ENTERS_ETA": invalid identifier.

Comment: If you’ve changed your code then it is always helpful to update your question with the latest version. Given that, your original code had enterTS_eta so I’m guessing you’ve made a typo and used enters_eta somewhere

Comment: Duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/q/17591707/1509264

Answer (score 1):

You have an additional AS alias internal to your column expression:

```
(EXTRACT (SECOND FROM a.service_date) AS servicedate_secs + a.eta) AS enterTS_eta,
```

Remove it:

```
(EXTRACT (SECOND FROM a.service_date) + a.eta) AS enterTS_eta,
```

Aliases are only used at the very end of the column expression.

Also, you don't need those outer parentheses around this, nor around the `CASE` expression, though they don't hurt anything. Parentheses are best used only when needed.

The next problem is that you're trying to use your derived column in the same query block.. you can't do that. That aliased name will only become available for use in a parent query block. So nest your query with two query blocks:

```
SELECT enterTS_eta,
       schdev,
       CASE 
             WHEN enterTS_eta < schdev 
                 THEN 'Schedule Deviation is more!'   -- Cases TO compare it WITH SchDev
             WHEN enterTS_eta > schdev 
                 THEN 'Schedule Deviation is less!'
             ELSE 'Equal!'
         END AS bus_log_info
   FROM (SELECT EXTRACT (SECOND FROM a.service_date)  + a.eta AS enterTS_eta, 
                a.schdev,    -- ADD - enter timestamp AND ETA
           FROM mytable a)
```

Comment: I tried that as well. But it gives me -
SQL Error [904] [42000]: ORA-00904: "ENTERS_ETA": invalid identifier.

Comment: Ah, I see.. you are trying to alias a column expression and then use that result in the same query block. I assumed you were replacing a column with a newly derived version. I'll update my answer then.